# Фокус только на форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть форма, установил свойство KeyPreview.
Поставил обработчик KeyPress. Перехватываю нажатие Enter, Backspace и стрелки вправо, влево.

Однако если на форме есть кнопка, то Enter не перехватывается. Как постоянно держать фокус на форме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если верить вот этому [ответу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140250/how-to-remove-the-focus-from-a-textbox-in-winforms), то ничего сделать нельзя так как контейнер(Например, Форма) передает фокус на первый дочерний элемент(Например, кнопка).

Однако, можно сделать какой-нибудь пустой Label и поставить focus на него и тогда ты не будешь нажимать на кнопку.

Comment: В общем, нужно на все кнопки поставить свойство TabStop = false, и при нажатии на эти кнопки ставить фокус на label. Пример: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_2hjwLrDDU&t=582s&ab_channel=ChrisMerritt